# Huge black bars on top and bottom of UI - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an issue with Views in the sample app I am trying to help me learn SwiftUI views.
The black bars at the top and bottom shouldn't be there. I want to extend the view to the top and bottom of the safe area limit.

Here is the code using Xcode 13.4.1 and iOS 15.5:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HotelView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                        .resizable()
                    Text("Home")
                }
            HomeView(title: "My Trips")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "suitcase")
                    Text("My Trips")
                }
            HomeView(title: "Saved")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "heart")
                    Text("Saved")
                }
            HomeView(title: "Profile")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                    Text("Profile")
                }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Also the HotelView file:

```
import SwiftUI


struct HotelView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(hotels) {  hotel in
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(hotels: hotel)) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(hotel.image)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(height: 100)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                                .overlay(
                                    Text(hotel.city)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white),alignment: .center)
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // navtitle
        }
    }
}
```

And the result in the simulator is:
[Black bars on top and bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ43I.jpg)

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Mohsin_city_plannerApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {

                ContentView()
            
            
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) Have you tried not to specify `frame` for `TabView` and let it take all available space on its own? (2) What's inside your `WindowGroup` of the `@main` `App`?

Comment: Why you are adding ScrollView with vertical direction in `List`? `List` by default has vertical scroll.

Comment: This is what u need to use scenedelegate to set rootvc.

Comment: Or just add `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` at the bottom of your top View

Comment: You need to make sure that your app has a launch storyboard or launch screen image or your app gets letterboxed

Comment: isn't launch storyboard or launch screen only for UIKit and not SwiftUI ?

Comment: I tried .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) on tabviewand it still has the letterbox. I removed scrollview on the list, didn't have an impact but its probably better not to use it.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Need to add launch screen to your info.plist]

So the solution is to add launch screen to your plist info file even in SwiftUI[image: No more black bars!!]

Comment: i am flabbergasted that that worked